# fputcsv Gives Warning When Handling Final Element of an Array

Tags: php

My question is about how to properly handle the following warning:

```
Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given
```

The offending lines are:

```
foreach($participantInfo as $fields)
{
    fputcsv($participantFile, $fields);
}
```

When I did a var_dump on `$fields`, I found two arrays as expected, but also a final `bool(false)`. Other than this, the code works as expected. Is there an appropriate way to handle the final bool, or should I just suppress the function warnings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$participantInfo  = array_filter($participantInfo );
foreach($participantInfo as $fields)
{
    fputcsv($participantFile, $fields);
}
```

This will remove all the entries eqal to FALSE from `$participantInfo`, deeper dimensions wil be untouched as your array is multidimensional.

Comment: This is a great answer considering the lack of knowledge of the contents of `participantInfo`

Comment: Daric - Thanks for the explanation.

Explosion Pills - Sorry I didn't mention it - participantInfo contains arrays that are the lines of a .csv file.